# PHP Array combining

Tags: php, arrays

What i am trying to achieve is to display all the session times and have each time with all the week days, then each week day will show one or more events if they have them.

I can get the times and week days but not the events for those days. i have provided my arrays and code to see if i can get some help.

My Session Times

```
Array
(
[06:00:00] => 06:00:00
[07:00:00] => 07:00:00
[08:00:00] => 08:00:00
[09:00:00] => 09:00:00
[09:30:00] => 09:30:00
[17:30:00] => 17:30:00
[18:00:00] => 18:00:00
[18:30:00] => 18:30:00
[19:30:00] => 19:30:00
)
```

My Events

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[class_id] => 1
[class_name] => Fit Box
[class_description] => Fitbox is a high energy aerobic workout utilizing focus pads, kick pads, heavy bags, and speed balls. This class increases muscle strength and cardiovascular fitness and also includes strength and endurance circuit style training. Excellent for co-ordination, reflexes and to pump out the adrenalin! The class is 1 hour in duration.
[class_time] => 06:00:00
[class_day] => Tuesday
[class_status] => active
[class_colour] => blue
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
[class_id] => 2
[class_name] => Hot Boxing
[class_description] => test description
[class_time] => 08:00:00
[class_day] => Wednesday
[class_status] => active
[class_colour] => grey
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
[class_id] => 3
[class_name] => Punch Face
[class_description] => test again
[class_time] => 09:00:00
[class_day] => Thursday
[class_status] => active
[class_colour] => grey
)

[3] => stdClass Object
(
[class_id] => 4
[class_name] => MOS
[class_description] => test again
[class_time] => 19:30:00
[class_day] => Monday
[class_status] => active
[class_colour] => yellow
)

[4] => stdClass Object
(
[class_id] => 5
[class_name] => Yoga
[class_description] => test description
[class_time] => 08:00:00
[class_day] => Wednesday
[class_status] => active
[class_colour] => grey
)

)
```

And this is my code that tries to do the job.

```
    $result_array = array();
$days_array = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

foreach($timetable_times as $time_key => $time_value)
{
    // initialize all the days of the week for each time entry
    $result_array[$time_value['time']] = array();
    foreach($days_array as $day) {
        $result_array[$time_value['time']][$day] = "";
    }

    if (array_key_exists($day, $timetable_classes)) {
        $event_entry = $timetable_classes[$time_value['time']];
        foreach($event_entry as $event_day => $events) {
            $result_array[$time_value['time']][$day][] = $events;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result_array);
```

I appreciate the help.

this is the outcome i am aiming for

```
$arr = array(
    "06:00:00" => array(
                                                    "Sunday" => array(
                                                            array(
                                                                'event_title' => "item_1",
                                                                'event_desc' => "item_1",
                                                                'event_link' => "item_1",
                                                            ),
                                                        ),  
                                                        "Monday" => array(
                                                                array(
                                                                        'event_title' => "item_1",
                                                                        'event_desc' => "item_1",
                                                                    'event_link' => "item_1",
                                                                        ),                                                                  
                                                                        array(
                                                                            'event_title' => "item_1",
                                                                            'event_desc' => "item_1",
                                                                            'event_link' => "item_1",
                                                                            ),
                                                                        ), 
                                                        "Tuesday" => "", 
                                                        "Wednesday" => "", 
                                                        "Thursday" => "", 
                                                        "Friday" => "", 
                                                        "Saturday" => ""
                                                        ),
                                     "07:00:00" => array("Sunday" => "", "Monday" => "", "Tuesday" => "", "Wednesday" => "", "Thursday" => "", "Friday" => "", "Saturday" => ""),
                                     "08:00:00" => array("Sunday" => "", "Monday" => "", "Tuesday" => "", "Wednesday" => "", "Thursday" => "", "Friday" => "", "Saturday" => ""),
                                     "09:30:00" => array("Sunday" => "", "Monday" => "", "Tuesday" => "", "Wednesday" => "", "Thursday" => "", "Friday" => "", "Saturday" => ""),
                                     "17:00:00" => array("Sunday" => "", "Monday" => "", "Tuesday" => "", "Wednesday" => "", "Thursday" => "", "Friday" => "", "Saturday" => ""),
                                     );
```

Comment: What are you talking about? this is driving me nuts

Comment: Can you try indenting your code correctly so its a little more readable? Not sure why you are getting down votes.

Comment: Indented the code for you

Comment: wonder why this got downvoted... seems like a pretty solid question with a reasonable attempt made at a solution.

Comment: @Orangepill Agreed. Its a good question, the code was just a little difficult to "parse". Not I that downvoted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off create a function that will search your list for entries matching the weekday and timeslot
(this implementation with closures requires php 5.3 but for older versions the implementation should be trivial)

```
<?php
function getClassesAt($day, $timeslot, $classes){
    $matches = array_filter($classes, function($class) use ($day, $timeslot){
        return ($class->class_day == $day && $class->class_time == $timeslot);
    });
    if(count($matches) == 0) return "";
    $ret = array();

    foreach($matches as $match){
        $ret[] = array("title"=>$class->class_name,
                        "description"=>$class->class_description,
                        "link"=>"???");
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Then build a container array that has an array with weekday keys for each session key

```
$days = array("Monday"=>"","Tuesday"=>"","Wednesday"=>"","Thursday"=>"","Friday"=>"","Saturday"=>"","Sunday"=>"");
$results = array_combine($sessions, array_pad(array(), count($sessions), $days));
```

an alternative to the last line of the above code would be

```
$results = array();
foreach ($sessions as $session){
     $results[$session] = $days;
}
```

Then walk the leafs of that array calling and assigning the the getClassesAt function.

```
foreach($results as $timeslot =>&$weekdays){
    foreach ($weekdays as $weekday=>$res){
        $weekdays[$weekday] = getClassAt($weekday, $timeslot, $classes);
    }
}
```

Warning this was only partially tested so I'm only about 60% sure that it will do what you want but the logic it's based on might point you in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

Based on the newly supplied code here is a working solution.

```
<?php
$classes = array(
                    array(
                        "class_id" => 1,
                        "class_name" => "Fit Box",
                        "class_description" => "description here",
                        "class_time" => "06:00:00",
                        "class_day" => "Tuesday",
                        "class_status" => "active",
                        "class_colour" => "blue",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "class_id" => 2,
                        "class_name" => "Hot Box",
                        "class_description" => "description here",
                        "class_time" => "08:00:00",
                        "class_day" => "Wednesday",
                        "class_status" => "active",
                        "class_colour" => "Red",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "class_id" => 3,
                        "class_name" => "Punch Face",
                        "class_description" => "description here",
                        "class_time" => "09:00:00",
                        "class_day" => "Thursday",
                        "class_status" => "active",
                        "class_colour" => "blue",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "class_id" => 4,
                        "class_name" => "MOS",
                        "class_description" => "description here",
                        "class_time" => "19:30:00",
                        "class_day" => "Monday",
                        "class_status" => "active",
                        "class_colour" => "blue",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "class_id" => 5,
                        "class_name" => "Yoga",
                        "class_description" => "description here",
                        "class_time" => "08:00:00",
                        "class_day" => "Wednesday",
                        "class_status" => "active",
                        "class_colour" => "blue",
                    ),
                );
$timetable_times = array(
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 1,
                        "time" => "06:00:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 2,
                        "time" => "07:00:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 3,
                        "time" => "08:00:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 4,
                        "time" => "09:00:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 5,
                        "time" => "09:30:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 6,
                        "time" => "17:30:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 7,
                        "time" => "18:00:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 8,
                        "time" => "18:30:00",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "time_id" => 9,
                        "time" => "19:30:00",
                    ),
                );  


function getClassesAt($day, $timeslot, $classes){
    $matches = array_filter($classes, function($class) use ($day, $timeslot){
        return ($class["class_day"] == $day && $class["class_time"] == $timeslot);
    });
    if(count($matches) == 0) return "";
    $ret = array();

    foreach($matches as $match){
        $ret[] = array("title"=>$match["class_name"],
                        "description"=>$match["class_description"],
                        "link"=>"???");
    }
    return $ret;
}


$sessions = array_map(function($a){return $a["time"]; }, $timetable_times);    
$days = array("Monday"=>"","Tuesday"=>"","Wednesday"=>"","Thursday"=>"","Friday"=>"","Saturday"=>"","Sunday"=>"");
$results = array_combine($sessions, array_pad(array(), count($sessions), $days));

foreach($results as $timeslot =>&$weekdays){
    foreach ($weekdays as $weekday=>$res){
        $weekdays[$weekday] = getClassesAt($weekday, $timeslot, $classes);
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [06:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Fit Box
                            [description] => description here
                            [link] => ???
                        )

                )

            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [07:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [08:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Hot Box
                            [description] => description here
                            [link] => ???
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Yoga
                            [description] => description here
                            [link] => ???
                        )

                )

            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [09:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Punch Face
                            [description] => description here
                            [link] => ???
                        )

                )

            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [09:30:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [17:30:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [18:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [18:30:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [19:30:00] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => MOS
                            [description] => description here
                            [link] => ???
                        )

                )

            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: firstly i get a _Array to string conversion_ error with this line `$results = array_combine($sessions, array_pad(array(), count($sessions), $days));`

Comment: That one works for me... what version of php are you running?

Comment: posted an alternative implementation of the line throwing the error

Comment: only showing events no time or day `
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Hot Boxing
            [description] => test description
            [link] => ???
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Yoga
            [description] => test description
            [link] => ???
        )

)
` This is what i get snippet

Comment: print_r $results after the first second step I posted... it should look something like this. Array
(
    [10:20] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

    [12:30] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 
            [Tuesday] => 
            [Wednesday] => 
            [Thursday] => 
            [Friday] => 
            [Saturday] => 
            [Sunday] => 
        )

)

Comment: It appears as though many of your inputs changed since the original question (objects became arrays and the format of the times changed)... Updated answer to reflect new inputs